# Thunderbird creates a folder called INBOX on IMAP

Tags: thunderbird, imap

Thunderbird creates a folder called INBOX on the IMAP server, and also a Trash folder inside it.

I guess it happened when I modified the settings, to move deleted messages to the Trash folder (on the IMAP server). There is already in a folder called Trash on the server.

When I choose `Account > Server Settings > When I delete a message: Move it to this folder` I see my IMAP root as `Inbox`. I can choose any of the existing folders. But something somewhere goes wrong, and instead of using the `Trash` folder on my IMAP root, TB creates a folder named INBOX and tries to access folders inside it.

Comment: `INBOX` (case-insensitive) is in fact required to exist on an IMAP server.

Comment: @grawity I don't think so. The messages go to the root of my imap folder. I guess Thunderbird calls the root of the IMAP folder itself `Inbox`, then for some strange reason thinks Inbox is a folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the [Config Editor](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings) and enter `trash_folder`.   Hopefully one of the items listed is `mail.server.server#.trash_folder_name`.  If the value is `INBOX/Trash` change it to `Trash`.  Exit from Thunderbird, then restart it.  If the *Trash* folder now has a recycle bin icon, then it worked and you should be able to delete the *INBOX* and *INBOX.Trash* folders.

I found the relevant details in http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP_Trash_folder, but I used the config editor rather than editing `prefs.js` directly.